# Can I use conditional formatting to format a cell based on color in the cell itself and the cell before?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Conditional formatting Excel 2010 how to format a cell based on color in the cell itself and the cell before.

I have with Conditional formatting marked a start cell and end cell with red I want to get all the cell between these two cells formatted with a red as well - can that be done?

e.g. with an IF statement saying if cell A21 is red and the current cell A22 isn't colored = True which will add the color it red to it which all true cells will be until and it gets that A44 and the current cell is red =false for the rest of the row.

Comment: What about a macro?

Comment: Please show your current rules. I think it will be easy to change them for coloring the cells in between.
As for your question, unfortunately it's not possible to create a Conditional Formatting rule that would work based on the colors created by other Conditional Formatting rules.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check for a color of any cell for conditional formatting, but you can select an entire range of cells and perform the conditional formatting on all those cells based on the content of one cell rather than all using the =formula.

So you basically want to duplicate the formula for the first conditioned cell, and use that on the other cells to make them color as that single cell changes.

Do note that if a condition is not met, the cell's original color is still used. You can also use conditional formatting to color a cell white to make it seem a condition undo's formatting.

Comment: The conditions won't be meet for these cells between the start and end date as it's what it is asking for - if the date above fits either the start or the end date then color the cell red but as I the periode between them is dynamic and I cant for each of the dates at least not very easily as I can see.. so conditional formattings can't validate on format or? can you see another way of coloring the cells between start and end cells red?

Comment: so basically you have a date in a cell, right? so your formula would check if that date is in between the start and end date, and if so, color it.